# One-( keypress-)event-delay between javascript input and output

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following snippet reproduces the input text in the webpage using simple javaScript and jQuery.

I am wondering, though, how come there is a one character (or more precisely : one keystroke) latency between the input and the output

**eg :**

1. I type 'abcde'
2. the output is 'abcd'
3. however if I press the Insert key, the ultimate 'e' prints.

My code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="enteredText" id="myTextInput" />

    <p id="myTextOutput">
    blabla 
    </p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $("#myTextInput").keypress(function( ){
    var theText = $("#myTextInput").val();
    $("#myTextOutput").html(theText); 
  });

$( "html" ).click(function( event ) {
 
    var value = $("#myTextInput").val();
    $("#myTextOutput").html(value); 
 
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're grabbing the value before you've allowed the event to propagate up to where the text field has been updated.  You can add an infinitesimal delay to get the full value:

```
$("#myTextInput").keypress(function( ){
    setTimeout(function() {
       var value = $("#myTextInput").val();
      $("#myTextOutput").html(value);
    }, 0);
  });
```

Comment: Yeah great, this seems to be the fastest responding fix amongst the following solutions : keyup/keydown/Timeout

Comment: You should just use the keyup event instead of the keypress with a timeout. That's just silly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of tat latency. use `keyup` or `keydown` instead of `keypress`:

```
$("#myTextInput").keyup(function( ){
    var value = $("#myTextInput").val();
    $("#myTextOutput").html(value); 
  });
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rv3544s8/)

Comment: `keydown` has the same issue as `keypress`, at least in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/mmojdaqe/

Comment: the reason I used keyup in my samples is that.

Comment: I know, just pointing it out since you suggest using `keydown` in the second sentence. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that the `keypress` event handler is executed before the content of the input field is updated. When you read the content, you still read the old content, not the updated one.

From jQuery's [`keypress` docs](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

Using `keyup` instead fixes the issue:

```js
  $("#myTextInput").keyup(function() {
    var theText = $("#myTextInput").val();
    $("#myTextOutput").html(theText);
  });

  $("html").click(function(event) {

    var value = $("#myTextInput").val();
    $("#myTextOutput").html(value);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="enteredText" id="myTextInput" />

<p id="myTextOutput">
  blabla
</p>
```